# Varying framerates in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, windows-7, directx-10

I think WoW may only be utilizing my SLI some of the time, or else Windows is not allocating it priority. I have two GeForce GTS 250's in SLI. Some of the time, WoW runs at 60 FPS when no characters or mobs are on the screen, and then drops down to about 40 when the screen is busier. Other times, it tops out at about 45, then drops down to about 30 when the screen is busy. Sometimes, if I alt-tab out and in that seems to fix it.

I am using Windows 7 and have the latest graphics drivers installed. This problem doesn't happen in other games.

Comment: Wow's frame rates have been a continual mystery for a long time.. I will see my FPS sit at around 40 running across 3 480 cards in SLI. I have opened up 5 instances of the game and all of them run at 40FPS. I have put 3 copies, one on each card.. and still the same.. Then the next time I play they all hop to 60...

Comment: Ok. I thought I was going crazy. I set it up to use realtime priority and that seemed to help a bit. (Make a batch file with the command: start /realtime [your wow directory and program file])

Answer (score 1):

Framerates in WoW, assuming your hardware is not overheating, can be determined by a number of factors;

- Network latency. Higher latency may result in choppier gameplay - especially when entering new areas.
- Background processes. WoW is very CPU intensive and background processes that demand CPU time may cause a drop in framerates.
- or as mentioned above, those two cards might just be overheating.